# How to pause animation right before it finishes with Web Animations API?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a library in javascript that does some animations with the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API). It seems that by default, once an animation has finished, everything visually resets to how it was before the animation started.

What is a reliable way to "pause" an animation in it's finished state, or immediately before the `onfinish` callback is executed?

Here is an example:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.pulse');
var animation = elem.animate(
  {
    opacity: [1, 0.5],
    transform: ['scale(1)', 'scale(0.5)']
  },
  {
    duration: 500
  }
);
animation.play();

// This works... but.. 10ms less than the duration?
// This cannot be very reliable...
setTimeout(function() {
  animation.pause();
}, 490);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/master/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<div class="pulse" style="width: 150px;">
  Hello world!
</div>
```

I want  to accomplish this without using a `setTimeout`. By the time the `onfinish` callback is executed, the animation is already over, and things look like they did when the animation was just starting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @andu-andrici's answer put me in the right direction, I was asking for a solution within the Web Animations API.

The solution was to add `fill: 'forwards'` to the object in the second argument of the `.animate()` call. Like so:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.pulse');
var animation = elem.animate(
  {
    opacity: [1, 0.5],
    transform: ['scale(1)', 'scale(0.5)']
  },
  {
    duration: 500,
    fill: 'forwards'
  }
);
animation.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/master/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<div class="pulse" style="width: 150px;">
    Hello world!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `CSS animation` with `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, which allows the animation to remain the way it was when it has finished ?

```
#shrink {
    position: relative;
    animation: myAnimation 500 forwards;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
    0%   { opacity:  1; transform:scale(1);  }
    100% { opacity: .5; transform:scale(.5); }
}
```